# Extract a row by value from php array

Tags: php, arrays

This is my array:

```
Array (
    [0] => Array ( [SocketID] => 1 [SocketName] => Name [SocketDecimal] => 0 [SocketHex] => 00 [SocketAtt] => 1 [Category] => 1 [Value] => 100 [Procentage] => 0 ) 
    [1] => Array ( [SocketID] => 2 [SocketName] => Name2 [SocketDecimal] => 50 [SocketHex] => 32 [SocketAtt] => 1 [Category] => 1 [Value] => 800 [Procentage] => 0 ) 
    [2] => Array ( [SocketID] => 3 [SocketName] => Name3 [SocketDecimal] => 100 [SocketHex] => 64 [SocketAtt] => 1 [Category] => 1 [Value] => 60 [Procentage] => 0 )
)
```

How can I extract a row by `SocketDecimal`?

For example: I want to extract row where `SocketDecimal = 50` and make new an array only with that row.

Comment: What do you mean by "extract" , echo ? create a new array ? write to a file ?

Comment: Have you tried something ?

Comment: Yes, i want to create a new array with that row

Comment: Edit your question with what your desired output should look like.

Comment: @MeTa It's a bit unclear what you want. But I think `array_column()` could be what you need

Comment: @Rizier123 I think he wants it the other way. I think he wants to have the entire record where socketdecimal = 50.

Comment: @Loko could also be; It's just unclear what OP wants so until he doesn't clarify the question it's just guesswork

Comment: @Rizier123 Even though I agree 100% with you that this is guesswork. I think it makes the most sense since I dont think he wants all the socketdecimal values where the value =50. Wouldn't make sense unless he wants to count the amount of values where value = 50 which still can be done in a better way.

Comment: @Loko Unfortunately i don't know a better way... this array is a mssql_fetch_assoc array. I make this array to stop spamming db with a lot of useless query

Comment: @MeTa The better way was about if you wanted just the value==50 returned but according to your accepted answer, you dont want that and treegardens answer is the right answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
foreach($array as $entry) {
    if($entry['SocketDecimal'] == 50)
        $newArr[] = $entry;
}
```

`$newArr` will contain the desired "row". Of course you can manipulate the if-statement depending on which "row" (I'd just call it array entry) you want to extract.

Comment: (If I'm right)I think this answer is the only one that understands the question. +1

Answer (score 1):

It's not the best way for big data! It's easy for deep multiarrays.

```
$arr = array(
array('socket_id'=>1,'name'=>'test1'),
array('socket_id'=>2,'name'=>'test2'),
array('socket_id'=>3,'name'=>'test3'),
array('socket_id'=>2,'name'=>'test4')
);

$newArr = array();
foreach($arr as $row){
    foreach($row as $key=>$r){
        if($key == 'socket_id' && $r==2)
        $newArr[] = $row;
    }
}
print_r($newArr);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$result = array();
foreach($input as $i){
   if($i['SocketDecimal']==50)
      $result[]=$i;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by this method

```
foreach ($yourarray as $key => $value){
    $newarray = array("SocketDecimal"=>$value["SocketDecimal"];
}

print_r($newarray);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
If your result array is like given below
$arr = array(
            array( 'SocketID' => 1, 'SocketName' => 'Name', 'SocketDecimal' => 0, 'SocketHex' => 0, 'SocketAtt' => 1, 'Category' => 1, 'Value' => 100, 'Procentage' => 0 ),
            array ( 'SocketID' => 2, 'SocketName' => 'Name2', 'SocketDecimal' => 50, 'SocketHex' => 32, 'SocketAtt' => 1, 'Category' => 1, 'Value' => 800, 'Procentage' => 0 ), 
            array ( 'SocketID' => 3, 'SocketName' => 'Name3', 'SocketDecimal' => 100, 'SocketHex' => 64, 'SocketAtt' => 1, 'Category' => 1, 'Value' => 60, 'Procentage' => 0 )
            );

print_r($arr);

Get row for SocketDecimal=50 by following loop:
<pre>
$resultArr = '';
foreach($arr as $recordSet)
{
    if($recordSet['SocketDecimal'] == 50)
    {
        $resultArr[] = $recordSet;
        break;
    }   
}
</pre>
print_r($resultArr);

break foreach loop so that it will not traverse for all the array when SocketDecimal(50) founded.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use array_column + array_search combo

```
$array = Array (
            "0" => Array ( "SocketID" => 1, "SocketName" => "Name", "SocketDecimal" => 0, "SocketHex" => 00, "SocketAtt" => 1, "Category" => 1, "Value" => 100, "Procentage" => 0 ) ,
            "1" => Array ( "SocketID" => 2, "SocketName" => "Name2", "SocketDecimal" => 50, "SocketHex" => 32, "SocketAtt" => 1, "Category" => 1, "Value" => 800, "Procentage" => 0 ),
            "2" => Array ( "SocketID" => 3, "SocketName" => "Name3", "SocketDecimal" => 100, "SocketHex" => 64, "SocketAtt" => 1, "Category" => 1, "Value" => 60 ,"Procentage" => 0 )
        );

var_dump($array[array_search(50,array_column($array,'SocketDecimal'))]);
```